# norm inequality with two vectors

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let V be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Let (V, ||·||) be a normed space.
Let $x,y\in V$, then $||x||\leq \max{\{||x+y||, ||x-y||\}}$
This may seem trivial but I am stuck with it.
I have tried with both triangle and reverse triangle inequality. But it only gets to this, $||x||\leq ||x-y|| + ||y||$ or $||x||\leq ||x||+||y||$.

Comment: stuck where? show what you have tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint:
$$
2\|x\|=\|(x+y)+(x-y)\|.
$$